# Is there a way to create a class to share a transition intent? [building my first android app]

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-transitions

What I am trying to achieve here is create a java class that will allow me to call the method inside the class for an activity transitioning.

For instance, I have 3 activities: Main.xml, A activity.xml, B activity.xml. I want to create a class that I can call from main's java class to transition to A and then from A to B.

I thought maybe it would be somewhere along that lines of:

[Transitioning activity class]
//Behind the scenes for activity transitioning, I don't know how to write this part or if calling it is correct

`Intent intent = new Intent(?, ?); startActivity(intent); overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);`

[Main]
//calling intent from activity transitioning class
`intent(this, A_activity.class);`

[A Activity]
//calling intent from activity transitioning class
`intent(this, B_activity.class);`

Also I want to apologize, this is indeed my first rodeo, I am self-taught and have no professional experience in programming or developing. Thank you in advance!

So far what I am currently doing is creating the transitions in each class:

[A activity]

```
public void onClick(View v){
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.commBtn:
            inqList.clear();
            inqAdd.addItem("Commercial");
            System.out.println(inqList);
            onTransition();
            break;
        case R.id.resBtn:
            inqList.clear();
            inqAdd.addItem("Residential");
            System.out.println(inqList);
            onTransition();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

//Method for transition after clicked
public void onTransition(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, b_scene.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in,R.anim.fade_out);
}
```

```
**[Edit]**
///I did this and it works? not sure if its best practice but it worked.

[Transition Class]

    public class Transition {
        public static void onTrans(Activity activity, Class name) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, name);
            activity.startActivity(intent);
            activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in,R.anim.fade_out);
        }
    }
```

```
[A Activity]
///Just put this in A activity

public void onClick(View v){
...
onTrans(this, B_Activity.class)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can but since that transition class is not an `Activity` instance (which has the `startActivity()` method), you need to pass the `Activity` instance as well, e.g.:

```
public static void navigateTo(Activity source, Activity destination) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, destination.class);
    source.startActivity(intent);
    source.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in,R.anim.fade_out); 
}
```

Another common option is to use an abstract  `BaseActivity` that has this method `onTransition()` and extend your activities from this one (you can also use composition instead of inheritance for a better practice).

Comment: Thank you for responding! I wish I knew about a book or a resource that has best practices so I could follow those guidelines. As for adding the activity to the onTransition, the portion where the intent is do I just put (activity, ?) what do I put in replacement for multi-use for the .class portion? Or am I misunderstanding your response?

Comment: Wait! Okay I think I got it actually, I am going to post my code, I think this got it working! Thanks again! It led me to the right direction!

Comment: Yes, exactly, you pass the new activity, my answer was lacking. I will edit it.

Comment: Also normally prefixing `on` on methods is reserved to callbacks. In this case you want to do an action, not listen for an action, so a better name would be `navigateTo()` for example. About best practices you can start with [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) and move on from there.

Comment: Awesome Thank you for your help! Ill put that in my activity instead! I wish I could upvote but need 15 reputation before I can :(. But I really appreciate it! Also will do, checking out SOLID and JetPack Navigation Library.

Comment: @JMStacky Of course, no problem. You might also be interested in taking a look at the [Jetpack Navigation library](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation).